# Oracle sql | Share generated by default on null as identity

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to share the same "pool" for ids when using following syntax?

```
create table TEST (
   ID INTEGER
      generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 nocycle noorder)  not null
      constraint CKC_ID  check (ID >= 0),
   constraint PK_ID  primary key (ID )
);


create table TEST2 (
   ID INTEGER
      generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 nocycle noorder)  not null
      constraint CKC_ID2  check (ID >= 0),
   constraint PK_ID2  primary key (ID )
);
```

When both attribute have the same name? The only possibility I came up was to start both at different values.
Like Test on 1000 and test 2 on 2000 but this is not a long term solution. I'm looking to a solution where I can "share" the same "pool" for ids, so that the id's will never overlap.

Comment: You can use a sequence instead of an identity column.

Comment: As Gordon says, you could use an explicit sequence to populate the PK column in both tables. But, are you sure your data model is correct? You should only care about PK value collisions if the entities are comparable (say a CARS and a TRUCKS table). If so, a better model is a single master VEHICLES table, with PK populated as identity, and common attributes such as manufacturer and date of production. Then have child tables with the attributes of each kind of vehicle. The PK in the child tables would also be FK to the master table, they don’t need to be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DEFAULT ON NULL` with a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq;

CREATE TABLE TEST (
   ID INT
      DEFAULT ON NULL TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL
      NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY
      CONSTRAINT CKC_ID  check (ID >= 0)
);

CREATE TABLE TEST2 (
   ID INT
      DEFAULT ON NULL TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL
      NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK_ID2 PRIMARY KEY
      CONSTRAINT CKC_ID2  check (ID >= 0)
);
```

Then if you insert some data:

```sql
INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( NULL );
INSERT INTO test2 ( id ) VALUES ( NULL );
INSERT INTO test2 ( id ) VALUES ( NULL );
INSERT INTO test ( id ) VALUES ( NULL );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  4 |
> ```

```sql
SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f442e5efc9801e555003efbf0b21449e)*